# Making text to go to center of the mobile screen without using media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I've a requirement where I'm supposed to write an hybrid app by using `phonegap`, `html`, `css`,`js` and `java`. And that hybrid app has to support wide range of devices (It is an international product). But I'm not supposed to use media queries. So I decided to use `bootstrap` which does a pretty decent job. However I've a problem.

I wrote a custom page by using bootstrap. code is [as given here.](http://jsfiddle.net/m3wqywft/):

**for `text` in `body`, I gave these `css`**

```
#loaderText{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.loaderPos{
    /*margin: 69px 101px;*/
    /*width: 50%;
    padding: 0 12%;*/
    padding-top: 22%;
    padding-left: 22%
}
```

The text appears to be at center in `portrait` mode, but appears to be out of context in `landscape` mode.

I could use a media query like this:
`media screen (min-height: 360px) and (orientation:landscape){ }` and add css there but the challenge is: Achieve proper alignment in both `portrait` and `landscape` mode without using `media queries`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: You know bootstrap uses media queries, right?

Comment: yeah, I know. But I'm not supposed to use my own media queries. Client expects `bootstrap` to manage all pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will advice you to use `flexbox`. It will make your content center aligned, both horizontally and vertically, only any device, no matter the height and width.

Make these changes in your styles. To know more go through [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) link

```
.mainDiv {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loaderPos {
  /* margin: 69px 101px; */
  /* padding-top: 22%; */
  /* padding-left: 22%; */
}
```

Comment: This is much better than previous one, works okay for tablets. Thank you

Comment: But I never used `vh` and `flex` earlier, great learning. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

As you want it without using `media-query` then you've to make changes in your `DOM` as well as in your `CSS` too.

HTML:

```
           <div id="loaderText">
                <p>Please wait while downloading data.</p><br />
                <p>This may take a few minutes.</p>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#loaderText{
   color: #fff;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
}

#loaderText p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.loaderPos{
  padding-top: 22%;
}
```

Also I've edited your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/m3wqywft/2/)   , please have a look.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni please check this, here in JSFiddle its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/m3wqywft/2/

Comment: But I think that this isn't the optimal solution for tablets. For mobiles, this is okay

Comment: @AjayKulkarni you are right, it is not optimal, please read my answer if you want  this to work on any device.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay no. jQuery is not necessary to make content center aligned. please go through my answer.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: Less code, more comfort to the developer. I'd not add extra jQuery for aligning :)